# Change multiple hgrc files from default = http to default = ssh and default-pull = http

Tags: regex, http, ssh, find, mercurial

I would like to change multiple mercurial hgrc files.

Starting file (example):

```
# example repository config (see "hg help config" for more info)
[paths]
default = http://ourmercurialserver.de/apps/

# path aliases to other clones of this repo in URLs or filesystem paths
...
```

Wanted result

```
# example repository config (see "hg help config" for more info)
[paths]
default = ssh://myusername@ourmercurialserver.de//path/to/repositories/apps/
default-push = http://ourmercurialserver.de/apps/

# path aliases to other clones of this repo in URLs or filesystem paths
...
```

I have created several commands. But the first doesn't work on Mac

1. Insert second line default-push with found expression default = http(*):

   ```
   find . -type f -name 'hgrc' -exec sed -i '' s/((^)default = http(.*)($))/\1\n\default-push = \1/ {} +
   ```

   Error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   (Error occurs with (^) and ($) and without)
2. Replace default-push = default = http with default-push = http:

   ```
   find . -type f -name 'hgrc' -exec sed -i '' s/((^)default-push = default = http)/default-push = http/ {} +
   ```
3. Does work :-) Replace the default http-String to an ssh-String:

   ```
   find . -type f -name 'hgrc' -exec sed -i '' s/default = http:\\/\\/ourmercurialserver.de/ssh:\\/\\/default = myusername@ourmercurialserver.de\\/\\/path\\/to\\/repositories/ {} +
   ```

Edit: My final Solution (Thanks to Torek & meistermuh)

1. Insert second line default-push

   ```
   find . -type f -name 'hgrc*' -exec sed -i '' -e 's,^default = http://\(.*\),default = http://nkoch@\1\
   default-push = http://\1,' {} +
   ```
2. Replace the default http-String to an ssh-String

   ```
   find . -type f -name 'hgrc' -exec sed -i '' 's,^default = http://myusername@ourmercurialserver.de,default = ssh://myusername@ourmercurialserver.de//path/to/repositories,' {} +
   ```

Comment: (^) and ($) might be a problem. simply remove the brackets since you don't need and actually also cannot group a 0-byte signal (^ and $ actually are not characters etc. but kind of a signal for "beginning of line" and "end of line")

Comment: thanks for fast reply. it doesn't matter if (^) and ($) are there or not. I always get the error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" will clairyfy in orginal post

Comment: aaah ok, I see. put your substitution in single quotes and only use round brackets for grouping patterns if you need to. example: `find . -type f -name 'hgrc' -exec sed -i '' 's/^default-push = default = http)/default-push = http/' {} +` 

in your first example, `\n` would also cause a problem since line breaks are not allowed in file names. 

btw.: i currently don't know why your third one is working at all since the empty single quotes prior to your substitution (in each example) seams to be misplaced to me

Comment: most important before you try: copy your files for having a backup ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(N.B.: This is not really a Mercurial issue, it's mainly just a shell and sed issue, with a side effect of regular expression stuff.  If you wanted to get particularly fancy, though, you might want to make sure that only `default = http://...` lines that *are in a `paths` section* are modified, and that requires much fancier work in `sed`, or using a real config-file reader.)

You have multiple issues here:

1. The shell likes to interpret and/or eat certain characters.

   The precise details depend on which shell you use.  Most shells share a simple convention, though: double quotes quote single quotes, and quote some other special characters such as `*`, but *do not* quote variable-name expansions like `$var` and other `$`-based expansions such as `$(subcommand)`.  Meanwhile, single quotes quote *everything* except single quotes.  (And, outside of either kind of quote, a backslash quotes *one* character, including another backslash or either kind of quote, so that if you just need to get one quote in, \" or \' will do the trick.)

   Parentheses are among the characters that shells tend to eat, so:

   ```
   echo (foo)
   ```

   is not a valid command.  You must quote the parentheses, e.g.:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo '(foo)'
   (foo)
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo \(foo\)
   (foo)
   ```

   Note that with `\(`, the `echo` command sees only the parenthesis—the backslash is *gone* (eaten by the shell) by the time `echo` runs.
2. `sed` needs to see `\(...\)` around regular expressions that must be captured.  These are literal backslashes and parentheses.  The same goes for replacements.  The entire `s/match/replace/` sequence must be a single word.  Hence this works:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo test | sed -e s/\\\(e.\*\\\)/captured\ \\\1/
   tcaptured est
   ```

   but it's much more readable as:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo test | sed -e 's/\(e.*\)/captured \1/'
   tcaptured est
   ```

   Using single quotes here means that we can use any except single quote.  This allows us to use `$` if desired.  There is no need here (since `.*` is a ["maximal-munch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)) but in general if you do not want `$` interpolation, you should use single quotes anyway.
3. If your goal is to replace a line that reads:

   ```
   default = http://whatever
   ```

   with *two* lines, you have a bit of a problem.  Let's start with something simpler:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo test | sed -e 's/\(e.*\)/
   > captured \1/'
   sed: 1: "s/\(e.*\)/
   captured \1/
   ": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
   ```

   This particular variant of `sed` (on my Mac) needs to see a backslash before the newline.  Hence:

   ```
   sh-3.2$ echo test | sed -e 's/\(e.*\)/\
   captured \1/'
   t
   captured est
   ```

   (Other variants of `sed` may allow newlines without prefix backslashes.)
4. (Minor) We'd probably like to use `/` in the pattern.  We *could* write this as, e.g., `s/foo\/bar/foo2\/bar2/`.  Fortunately we do not have to use `s/foo/bar/`, we can use any other character that *doesn't* occur in the pattern such as `s,foo/bar,foo2/bar2,`.

Fortunately `find` does not pass arguments directly to the shell.  If it did you'd have a fifth problem, but we have now covered all the problems. :-)  We can now first write a `sed` command that works, and test it:

```
sh-3.2$ echo default = http://foo > foo.txt
sh-3.2$ sed -e 's,^default = http://\(.*\),default = ssh://myusername@\1\
> default-push = http://\1,' < foo.txt
default = ssh://myusername@foo
default-push = http://foo
```

This seems to work, so now we can have the command do the in-place editing by adding `-i ''`:

```
sh-3.2$ sed -i '' -e 's,^default = http://\(.*\),default = ssh://myusername@\1\
default-push = http://\1,' foo.txt
sh-3.2$ cat foo.txt
default = ssh://myusername@foo
default-push = http://foo
```

Note: I've used your example from your "Wanted result" text, which contradicts the example in the question subject.  Make sure your final command sequence does what you *want* before running it (or, as [meistermuh suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688513/mercurial-change-mutliple-hgrc-files-from-default-http-to-default-ssh-and-d#comment86389186_49688513), keep backups—maybe use something other than `-i ''`!).